# Style target behaviors MAUI

Tags: maui, setter, eventtocommand

I want to create styled editor for my current page. I use it few times so i decide to wrote style for this element and wondering how to use Behaviors inside style. If i do this like regular way, everything is working fine

```
<Editor Style="{StaticResource TestEditor}"/>
<Editor.Behaviors>
<toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior 
                        EventName="Unfocused"
                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestEditorPage}, Path=BindingContext.UnfocusedCommand}"
                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                        
                    </toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior>

</Editor.Behaviors>
</Editor>
```

So how to do the same but in my style if it is possible:

```
 <Style x:Key="TestEditor"
           TargetType="Editor">

        <Setter Property="AutoSize" Value="TextChanges"/>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Placeholder" Value="Enter question answer"/>
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:TestAnswerResponce}}, Path=Answer}"/>

        <Setter Property="Behaviors">

            <!-- Behavior -->
            
        </Setter>           
        
    </Style>
```

Comment: [doc section: Consume Maui Behavior with a Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/behaviors#consume-a-net-maui-behavior-with-a-style). If you get this working, go ahead and create Your Answer below, showing your final code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, creating a style that sets the Behaviors property of a control is not possible because the property is read-only. The solution is to add an attached property to the behavior class that controls adding and removing the behavior.

As a workaround, you could set the value of attach property to EventToCommandBehavior. Try the following code:

First, create a behaviour class in which adds an attached property.

```
public class MyEditorStyleBehavior : Behavior<Editor>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AttachBehaviorProperty =
            BindableProperty.CreateAttached("AttachBehavior", typeof(object), typeof(MyEditorStyleBehavior), null,propertyChanged: OnAttachBehaviorChanged);

    public static object GetAttachBehavior(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (object)view.GetValue(AttachBehaviorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAttachBehavior(BindableObject view, object value)
    {
        view.SetValue(AttachBehaviorProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnAttachBehaviorChanged(BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Editor editor = view as Editor;
        if (editor == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        EventToCommandBehavior attachBehavior = newValue as EventToCommandBehavior;
        editor.Behaviors.Add(attachBehavior);
    }
}
```

And in xaml, consume the behaviour.

This is my xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>

<Style x:Key="TestEditor" TargetType="Editor">

   <Setter Property="AutoSize" Value="TextChanges"/>

   <Setter Property="Placeholder" Value="Enter question answer"/>
   <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding MyEditorText}"/>

    <Setter Property="local:MyEditorStyleBehavior.AttachBehavior">
        <Setter.Value>
            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior  EventName="Unfocused" 
               Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestEditorPage}, Path=BindingContext.UnfocusedCommand}"
               />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Editor x:Name="myeditor" Style="{StaticResource TestEditor}"/>

        <Editor x:Name="myeditor1" Style="{StaticResource TestEditor}"/>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In code behind .cs file, don't forget to set the bindingContext for the page.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
}
```

In ViewModel, I define the UnfocusedCommand and MyEditorText property. And each time editor lose focus (tap the entry below it), the command will fire.

```
public string MyEditorText { get; set; }

public Command UnfocusedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("12345");
        });
    }
}

public MainPageViewModel()
{
    MyEditorText = "MyEditorText";
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work. I made my style behavior class like you recommend, than added reference to this behavior on my page like this:
`xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Behaviors"`
and than used inside my style like this
`<Setter Property="behaviors:TestEditorStyleBehavior.AttachBehavior">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Unfocused"
                                                        Command="{Binding UnfocusedCommand}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>`

Comment: Did it throw any error? And you can first check if the binding work. In the Style we also bind the text to MyEditorText property in ViewModel. Check if this property works. I have tested my code on iOS and Android and it worked.

Comment: No, it doesn’t throw any errors, it’s just not triggered. And I also don’t need command parameter, because I bind my entries text to model properties and inside my command I just need to do some work

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use a command parameter or not. You can just delete it.

Comment: And how you make the editor to be unfocused?

Comment: So I type some text inside my editor and then when I leave text editor unfocused event triggered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253591/discussion-between-death-dealer-and-liqun-shen-msft).

Comment: So problem is that i use my style inside datatemplate and i needed to change command binding to `Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestEditorPage}, Path=BindingContext.UnfocusedCommand}"` instead of  `Command={Binding UnfocusedCommand}`

Comment: Yes，I agree with you